# Spring + Hibernate + Rest crossing reference?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I have application that use rest to operate on database.

I have 2 entities: Question and Answer:

Question.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QUESTIONS")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String question;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answer> answers;
    ...
```

Answer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWERS")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String answer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Question relatedQuestion;
    private boolean correct;
    ...
```

I want to POST question object by REST endpoint to have proper references between question and answers.

If i POST:

```
{
    "question": "What is the best animal in the world?",
    "answers": [
        {
            "answer": "cow",
            "correct": false
        },
        {
            "answer": "crocodile",
            "correct": false
        },
        {
            "answer": "murloc",                
            "correct": true
        }
    ]
}
```

relatedQuestion field will be null.

In another words: what to put in `?` place?

```
{
      "answer": "crocodile",
      "correct": false,
      "relatedPost": ?
}
```

How to solve this problem? Maybe this structure is wrong?

Comment: Mariusz, can you please clarify what you expect the response to a question to be?  Is relatedQuestion a bi-directional link back to the original question, is it a different question, or should it be a list of all related questions?  Thank you.

Comment: `relatedQuestion` is bidirectional link. I dont know how to represent such model in json.

Comment: After you post the json above, you will have a Question object (question), which contains three Answers in a list.  My understanding is that you then have to iterate through the answers, and set answer.setRelatedQuestion(question) prior to persisting.  Or am I still not understanding.

Comment: I've edited my question. I hope it's more clearly. I have found solution for avoiding infinite recursion while converting model to json but i dont know how to make conversion from json to my model (Question.java and Answer.Java)

Comment: So the user who is posting the json above (i.e. building a new question with a set of answers - one correct, and others wrong) - they have already run a GET /questions? And they will assign a relatedPost to each answer?  Then relatedPost: is the PK of Question.id?  Example: "relatedPostId": 3

Comment: But I don't know how they will assign something to `relatedPost` if users have only access to endpoint `/questions`. Assignment should be made in some automated way.
UPDATE
I think I found solution. In Question class, in setAnswers method I iterate over answer set and assign references. It is enough for now.

Comment: Agreed.  This is what I was referring to in my second comment.  Good luck